# IndoorAtlas cordova plugin with Ionic 4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, indoor-positioning-system

I am building a new app with Ionic 4, and I would like to try out IndoorAtlas indoor geomagnetic positioning system (seems very promising as a technology!). But I cannot find a way to include the cordova plugin properly (most certainly due to my newbieness).

Has anyone played with this and can shed some light?

I tried installing the plugin from github

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/cordova-plugin.git
```

Since it is not a ionic native plugin,I tried calling it with `window.plugins` and `window['plugins']` as some other posts suggested for non-native cordova plugins, but both are undefined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use this type of plugin declare one variable named 'cordova' after your import statement and before @Component() declaration as below :

```js
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
...
...

declare var cordova; // <====== declare this

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now, you can use that cordova variable to access your plugin's method like :

```js
cordova.plugins.pluginName.methodName();
```

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you TestDPSjaksf.
I might be missing something (I am used to Native plugins that are easy to import and use): can you give me a hint about the import statement?

I tried ```import { } from 'cordova-plugin-indooratlas'```but cordova-plugin-indooratlas is not recognized as module...

Comment: If I just add what you said: ```declare var cordova;```
And then I try to use it like ```cordova.plugins.IndoorAtlas...``` I get:
```Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'IndoorAtlas' of undefined```

I am sure I am missing a pretty basic step :-S

Comment: Ok. Try to declare like `declare var cordova:any`.

Comment: :-( same error... cordova.plugins is still undefined...
Just for clarification: I am running this on physical device, and after the platform is ready...
Thank you for your help TestDPSjaksf, I appreciate it! I must still be missing something...